# SQL to select records where two values in one table are both present as substrings in a text field in a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
TableOne:    LNAME      FNAME     FILETYPE
             Smith      John      A
             Jones      Mary      B
             Brown      James     B

TableTwo:    NAME                 FILETYPE
             Mary Smith           1
             Smith, Mary Jane     2
             Brown, James         3
```

Tricky one to explain.

I have two tables (not huge - several thousand records). The relevant fields are in the example above. What I need to pull out would be, algorithmically:

```
SELECT
    TableOne.LName, TableOne.FName, TableOne.FileType, TableTwo.Name
WHERE
    (TableTwo.Name LIKE *LName* AND TableTwo.name LIKE *FName*)
    AND
    (IF TableOne FileType = 'A' THEN
        TableTwo.FileType = '1'
     ELSE IF TableOne FileType = 'B' THEN
        TableTwo.FileType = '2' OR TableTwo.FileType = '3'
    )
```

Obviously that's not a solution, just a clumsy type of psuedocode.
I've not posted any of my attempts from the last couple of hours because they've not even come close (they've involved temporary tables and sub-queries).

I know that this is never going to be 100% accurate - there are too many typos in that NAME field to start with - I just need to find a starting point based on records where there is a reasonable chance that there is no entry in TableTwo to match up with TableOne.

I'm tempted to give up and just do the job in Python (I'd like to think I could have done it in the time it's taken to type this), but I'd like to see if it can be done in SQL

Comment: This is a fairly ugly problem to have to handle from SQL, especially SQL Server.  The problem is that there are so many edge cases to consider.  For example, there may or may not be a middle name.  The last name might be two words (e.g. `Van Damme`), so it might not be possible to distinguish between a two word last name and a single middle and last name.  You may have to do some manual work here.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen Stops me from feeling quite as dumb as I have been. Re your name examples - that's why I settled on the simple wildcard approach. It's good enough (as a start) to just know that first and last names are both present anywhere as substrings of the name field.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to check if the first and last names appear as substrings, anywhere, in the full name in the second table, then we can try the following simple join:

```
SELECT
    t1.LName,
    t1.FName,
    t1.FileType,
    t2.Name
FROM TableOne t1
INNER JOIN TableTwo t2
    ON PATINDEX('%' + t1.FName + '%', t2.Name) > 0 AND
       PATINDEX('%' + t1.LName + '%', t2.Name) > 0
WHERE
    (t1.FILETYPE = 'A' AND t2.FILETYPE = 1) OR
    (t1.FILETYPE = 'B' AND t2.FILETYPE IN (2, 3));
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
    t1.LName,
    t1.FName,
    t1.FileType,
    t2.Name
FROM TableOne t1
JOIN TableTwo t2 ON
    t2.NAME LIKE '%'+t1.LNAME+'%' AND
    t2.NAME LIKE '%'+t1.FNAME+'%' AND
    t1.FILETYPE = CASE WHEN t2.FILETYPE = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35b5a5e1a5fa4628ebff86fb277d78f5)

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer keeping `JOIN` conditions in the `ON` clause and not using `CASE` for boolean expressions.

So:

```
SELECT t1.LName, t1.FName, t1.FileType, t2.Name
FROM TableOne t1 JOIN
     TableTwo t2
     ON t2.Name LIKE '%' + LName + '%' AND  
        t2.name LIKE '%' + FName + '%' AND
        ((t1.FileType = 'A' AND t2.FileType = 1) OR
         (t1.FileType = 'B' AND t2.FileType IN (2, 3))
        );
```